# How to Send Object Values in PostMan From FromData Calling a Web Api .net Method

Tags: c#, .net, api, .net-core, postman

I have a post Api method in my web api net core application thats has a Dto Class with the follow parameters:

```
public class ClassDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Comunicacao Comunicacao { get; set; }
    }
```

Comunicacao Class:

```
public class Comunicacao
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Api Action(route has been setted correctly):

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Add([FromForm]ClassDto bannerDto, IFormFile imgDesktop)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    var result = await _banner.Add(classDto, imgDesktop);

                    return Ok(new { message = result.messageReturning, result.classDto });
                }
                else
                {
                    return BadRequest(ModelState);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                return BadRequest(ex.ToLogString(Environment.StackTrace));
            }
        }
```

So my question is, how can i send in postman using FormData passing Comunicacao Object Values? Because when i sent "Id", it works fine, but i cant find a way to send objects!

[what i have tried yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlN8Q.jpg)

I cannot use FromBody because as you all can see im sending a File as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got it.
Have to use the object.property!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

put the iformfile object inside your dto making it a single dto method then ur endpoint will look like public async Task Add([FromForm]ClassDto bannerDto)
        if you have put the iformfile outside cos of automapper then u can use [ignore] attribute over the property

sorry wanted to put this as comment for the previous answer but i am typing from mobile phone so ...meh

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, it's really helpful, and yeah, i use automapper in the service class like: ``_mapper.Map(classDto, class);`` but for some reason i cant use ``.ForMember`` method in this block of code, maybe I should create a class just for maps and use ``CreateMap(class, classDto).ForMember(x => x.File, o => o.ignore()) ``? Thanks for the help again man, and sorry if my questions looks stupid, im learning :)

Answer (score 0):

you can set body type to form-data and then in key value pair side just select file instead of text for your file upload

[image: Postman screenshot]

Comment: file is good, im not having trouble with that, the point is ``ClassDto bannerDto`` is not receiving any values from Form Data, its always null. Based on what you said I tried to select a .txt json file with the parameters like: ``{
 "Id": 1,
 "Comunicacao": {"ImagemDesktop":"Teste"}
}`` but that doesnt worke either